# Google Wallet API Permission Denied

Tags: google-pay

I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/wallet/generic/web#node.js) guide for creating a Google Wallet pass. After even running the Github Code [here](https://github.com/google-pay/wallet-samples/blob/main/nodejs/demo-generic.js) I still only get an '403 Forbidden' error:

`error on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/hFmwR3qt`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit 1:
I should probably have mentioned that I have got an issuer account created on the Google Pay Business console.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. This answer helped me:
[Google Wallet API Codelabs example permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72253521/google-wallet-api-codelabs-example-permission-denied)

Just to add some points of clarity:
When you get your Issuer Id and Pass Class Id, Google is *prepending* the Issuer Id *to* the Pass Class Id. They shouldn't be doing this, and you need to remove it.
[image]

You should take only the part of the "Pass Class Id" that comes *after the dot*.

Next, notice the "Owner".

That is the email address you typed in when you clicked "Create" for a Temporary issuer. That email address must be the "client_email" value found in your key.json file (Line 6 in the file).

Comment: As I said in my question, I've not been following the codelab but just followed the guide on the docs. I should've probably mentioned that I've got a permanent issuer account created on the Google Pay Business console